# Do I need a new dataset each time that I filter by a new date range in Charts.js?

Tags: chart.js

I'm working on time line charts on a project and now I'm adding a date range filter. I'm wondering if to update my charts by the range selected, do I need to execute an ajax getting new datasets or is there someway to simply filtering the start and end date of the currents datasets and update the charts with javascript dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no build-in-function for that in `chart.js`. But you don't need a new ajax-request. Best way to do is filter your data with Javascript, make new data arrays and display them.